# How to apply Naive Bayes model to new data

Tags: r, naivebayes

I asked a question on this this morning but am deleting that and posting here with more betterer wording.

I created my first machine learning model using train and test data. I returned a confusion matrix and saw some summary stats.

I would now like to apply the model to new data to make predictions but I don't know how.

Context: Predicting monthly "churn" cancellations. Target variable is "churned" and it has two possible labels "churned" and "not churned".

```
    head(tdata)
  months_subscription nvk_medium                                org_type     churned
1                  25       none                               Community not churned
2                   7       none                            Sports clubs not churned
3                  28       none                            Sports clubs not churned
4                  18    unknown Religious congregations and communities not churned
5                  15       none              Association - Professional not churned
6                   9       none              Association - Professional not churned
```

Here's me training and testing:

```
 library("klaR")
 library("caret")

# import data
test_data_imp <- read.csv("tdata.csv")

# subset only required vars
# had to remove "revenue" since all churned records are 0 (need last price point)
variables <- c("months_subscription", "nvk_medium", "org_type", "churned")
tdata <- test_data_imp[variables]

#training
rn_train <- sample(nrow(tdata),
                   floor(nrow(tdata)*0.75))
train <- tdata[rn_train,]
test <- tdata[-rn_train,]
model <- NaiveBayes(churned ~., data=train)

# testing
predictions <- predict(model, test)
confusionMatrix(test$churned, predictions$class)
```

Everything up till here works fine.

Now I have new data, structure and laid out the same way as tdata above. How can I apply my model to this new data to make predictions? Intuitively I was seeking a new column cbinded that had the predicted class for each record.

I tried this:

```
## prediction ##
# import data
data_imp <- read.csv("pdata.csv")
pdata <- data_imp[variables]

actual_predictions <- predict(model, pdata)

#append to data and output (as head by default)
predicted_data <- cbind(pdata, actual_predictions$class)

# output
head(predicted_data)
```

Which threw errors

```
actual_predictions <- predict(model, pdata)
Error in object$tables[[v]][, nd] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(1:6433[[4L]], ...) :
  Numerical 0 probability for all classes with observation 1
2: In FUN(1:6433[[4L]], ...) :
  Numerical 0 probability for all classes with observation 2
3: In FUN(1:6433[[4L]], ...) :
  Numerical 0 probability for all classes with observation 3
```

How can I apply my model to the new data? I'd like a new data frame with a new column that has the predicted class?

** following comment, here is head and str of new data for prediction**

```
head(pdata)
  months_subscription nvk_medium                                org_type     churned
1                  26       none                               Community not churned
2                   8       none                            Sports clubs not churned
3                  30       none                            Sports clubs not churned
4                  19    unknown Religious congregations and communities not churned
5                  16       none              Association - Professional not churned
6                  10       none              Association - Professional not churned
> str(pdata)
'data.frame':   6433 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ months_subscription: int  26 8 30 19 16 10 3 5 14 2 ...
 $ nvk_medium         : Factor w/ 16 levels "cloned","CommunityIcon",..: 9 9 9 16 9 9 9 3 12 9 ...
 $ org_type           : Factor w/ 21 levels "Advocacy and civic activism",..: 8 18 18 14 6 6 11 19 6 8 ...
 $ churned            : Factor w/ 1 level "not churned": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: How does the data in variable `pdata` look like? Could you please add the result of `head(pdata)`?

Comment: Hi @tguzella the exact same as tdata except all instances of churned say "not churned" (since I'd like to predict which will churn"

Comment: Well, given the error I am inclined to think that the data is not the same as `tdata`... The error seems to be triggered when processing a feature that is a factor. However, if you don't show the data it is essentially impossible to tell what is going wrong

Comment: Hi @tguzella I was on mobile earlier so could not add the data. But I've added the head and str of pdata now. Any pointers or help very much welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a mismatch in the encoding of factors in the training data (variable `tdata` in your case) and the new data used in the `predict` function (variable `pdata`), typically that you have factor levels in the test data that are not present in the training data. Consistency in the encoding of the features must be enforced by you, because the `predict` function will not check it. Therefore, I suggest that you double-check the levels of the features `nvk_medium` and `org_type` in the two variables.

The error message:

```
 Error in object$tables[[v]][, nd] : subscript out of bounds
```

is raised when evaluating a given feature (the `v`-th feature) in a data point, in which `nd` is the numeric value of the factor corresponding to the feature. You also have warnings, indicating that the posterior probabilities for all the cases in data points ("observation") 1, 2, and 3 are all zero, but it is not clear if this is also related to the encoding of the factors...

To reproduce the error that you are seeing, consider the following toy data (from http://amunategui.github.io/binary-outcome-modeling/), which has a set of features somewhat similar to that in your data:

```
# Data setup
# From http://amunategui.github.io/binary-outcome-modeling/
titanicDF <- read.csv('http://math.ucdenver.edu/RTutorial/titanic.txt', sep='\t')
titanicDF$Title <- as.factor(ifelse(grepl('Mr ',titanicDF$Name),'Mr',ifelse(grepl('Mrs ',titanicDF$Name),'Mrs',ifelse(grepl('Miss',titanicDF$Name),'Miss','Nothing'))) )
titanicDF$Age[is.na(titanicDF$Age)] <- median(titanicDF$Age, na.rm=T)
titanicDF$Survived <- as.factor(titanicDF$Survived)
titanicDF <- titanicDF[c('PClass', 'Age',    'Sex',   'Title', 'Survived')]

# Separate into training and test data
inds_train <- sample(1:nrow(titanicDF), round(0.5 * nrow(titanicDF)), replace = FALSE)
Data_train <- titanicDF[inds_train, , drop = FALSE]
Data_test <- titanicDF[-inds_train, , drop = FALSE]
```

with:

```
> str(Data_train)

'data.frame':   656 obs. of  5 variables:
    $ PClass  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1st","2nd","3rd": 1 3 3 3 1 1 3 3 3 3 ...
$ Age     : num  35 28 34 28 29 28 28 28 45 28 ...
$ Sex     : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 ...
$ Title   : Factor w/ 4 levels "Miss","Mr","Mrs",..: 2 2 2 1 2 4 3 2 3 2 ...
$ Survived: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...

> str(Data_test)

'data.frame':   657 obs. of  5 variables:
    $ PClass  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1st","2nd","3rd": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Age     : num  47 63 39 58 19 28 50 37 25 39 ...
$ Sex     : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
$ Title   : Factor w/ 4 levels "Miss","Mr","Mrs",..: 2 1 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 ...
$ Survived: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Then everything goes as expected:

```
model <- NaiveBayes(Survived ~ ., data = Data_train)

# This will work
pred_1 <- predict(model, Data_test)

> str(pred_1)
List of 2
$ class    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:657] "6" "7" "8" "9" ...
$ posterior: num [1:657, 1:2] 0.8352 0.0216 0.8683 0.0204 0.0435 ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : chr [1:657] "6" "7" "8" "9" ...
.. ..$ : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
```

However, if the encoding is not consistent, e.g.:

```
# Mess things up, by "displacing" the factor values (i.e., 'Nothing' 
# will now be encoded as number 5, which was not present in the 
# training data)
Data_test_2 <- Data_test
Data_test_2$Title <- factor(
    as.character(Data_test_2$Title), 
    levels = c("Dr", "Miss", "Mr", "Mrs", "Nothing")
)

> str(Data_test_2)

'data.frame':   657 obs. of  5 variables:
    $ PClass  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1st","2nd","3rd": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Age     : num  47 63 39 58 19 28 50 37 25 39 ...
$ Sex     : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
$ Title   : Factor w/ 5 levels "Dr","Miss","Mr",..: 3 2 3 4 4 3 4 3 3 3 ...
$ Survived: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
```

then:

```
> pred_2 <- predict(model, Data_test_2)
Error in object$tables[[v]][, nd] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Thank you very much that makes sense. I looked at medium and org_type and found a long tail of levels with low count so grouped them at a higher level by reducing he variances (levels?) to 6. Everything is working as expected now! Thanks